# Get DownloadURL from an uploaded File

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I want to know how to get the `getDownloadURL()` when i uploaded an file. I want to upload an file and get the downloadURL for the file and then store it the Database.
Can you give an example how to do it in one function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String filePath = "videoTitle.mp4";
    StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(filePath);
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask =
        ref.putFile(video, StorageMetadata(contentType: "video/mp4"));


    await uploadTask.onComplete;
    if (uploadTask.isComplete) {
      String downloadUrl = await ref.getDownloadURL();
      return downloadUrl;
    }
```